# Progress OpenEdge to PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, odbc, openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

I have problem with converting Progress OpenEdge database to PostgreSQL. I have downloaded ODBC from [here](https://www.progress.com/trial-datadirect) and when i make ODBC connection (32 bit) in my computer, the connection is established. Next, I downloaded **Ispirer SQLWays Wizard 2015** from [here](http://www.ispirer.com/download/download-demo) (with some limitations, 100 tables max, 2gb od data etc), and tried to make conversion. All seem fine, source and destination databases are connected, I select only 1 table (just for test), but when I start conversion i get some weird error:

> [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Access denied (Authorization failed) (7512)

I kinda looked into this error and saw that solution should be:

1. Open the SQL Explorer and connect as 'sysprogress' (no password)
2. Grant DBA privilege to the desired user:

Any help how to do that? Or is there any other tool/way how to convert from Progress OpenEdge to PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3):

To run sql explorer first open a "proenv" window (you can find this in the Progress "program group").  Proenv is a command line window that has all of the necessary Progress environment prepared for you.  Once that is open you can use sqlexp to connect to any running database that has remote connections enabled.  A command similar to:

```
proenv> sqlexp -user userName -password passWord -db dbName -S servicePort -infile myScript.sql -outfile myScript.log
```

If you omit "-infile myScript.sql -outfile myScript.log" you will be dropped into a SQL command interpreter.

The specific content of "myScript.sql" (or any commands that you type) depend on what you are trying to accomplish.  However -- it is very important to remember to "commit work;"  If you do not do so then nothing you do will be saved when you exit.

This Progress kbase article has very detailed explanation including how to create users and grant DBA privileges:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/20143/p