# How to send data from Progress OpenEdge db to PostgreSQL if table data changes?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, openedge, progress-db

we have Progress OpenEdge db and PostgreSQL, if table data changes in Progress db then we have to same in PostgreSQL db.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Progress OpenEdge to PostgreSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45607530/progress-openedge-to-postgresql-database)

Answer (score 0):

There is no silver bullet.  But with a bit of work you could get it done:

Progress has an optional product called "CDC" for Change Data Capture which allows you to detect changed data, log the changes and then use your own logic to export the data.

You need OpenEdge 11.7 or better to run it.

https://www.progress.com/openedge/components/openedge-change-data-capture?&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=progress-openedge-cdc-search&gclid=Cj0KCQiAno_uBRC1ARIsAB496IXd6R1acqLMF2lM53Z1tjIFk-ON1J86lAnhkngoJzhKVQW2X-9zHkQaAq92EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

There is another, related, product called Pro2 but I do not believe that it supports PostgresSQL as a target (although I could be wrong about that).

If you don't want to go down that road then you would need to implement something similar with replication triggers (Pro2 was originally based on replication triggers and can still use them).  No extra license is needed and they are available in any modern release.  But you will have to "roll your own" logic and the effort will be greater.

A third option would be to pervert the auditing subsystem.  Your changed data could be audit events and you could probably write some logic to extract the changed data from the audit logs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing CDC in your Progress database and then streaming changes from there to your target database (in your example, PostgreSQL) using some messaging system.

I have created something similar from Progress OpenEdge to AWS Redshift using Kafka with Confluent Platform. It's not a trivial job, but it works pretty well.

In this scenario, you would enable OpenEdge CDC in your source Progress database, then create some SQL views over the tables you want changes to be tracked. Then you'd set up Kafka Connect to query these views using a JDBCSourceConnector, just to sink the messages from these views to your target database using a JDBCSinkConnector to PostgreSQL. Any ETL operations can be handled using KSQL environment.

Refer to this Progress article on how to stream data from OpenEdge to Kafka: https://www.progress.com/tutorials/jdbc/streaming-your-data-from-openedge-to-kafka

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33903333)